# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'file' not registered

Tags: arcgis-android

I have Android/Java code that adds layer to a `MapView`, calling a RESTful service, like so:

```
mDynamicServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(getResources().getString(R.string.some_url));
mMapView.addLayer(mDynamicServiceLayer);
```

This works fine. I want to also add a layer that is an mxd file on the device

```
<string name="mxd_file">file://storage/emulated/0/Download/mymap.mxd</string>

mDynamicServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(getResources().getString(R.string.mxd_file));
mMapView.addLayer(mDynamicServiceLayer);
```

This throws the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scheme 'file' not registered.
```

How do I do this?